# How should I handle music key (scale) as a feature in the knn algorithm

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, knn

I'm doing a data science project, and I was wondering how to handle a music key (scale) as a feature in the KNN algorithm.
I know KNN is based on distances, therefore giving each key a number like 1-24 doesn't make that much sense (because key number 24 is close to 1 as much as 7 close to 8).
I have thought about making a column for "Major/Minor" and another for the note itself,
but I'm still facing the same problem, I need to specify the note with a number, but because notes are cyclic I cannot number them linearly 1-12.

For the people that have no idea how music keys work my question is equivalent to handling states in KNN, you can't just number them linearly 1-50.

Comment: I do not know about music. Are you meaning that there are 50 music key without any relation between them?

Comment: Can you provide a sample to enter the KNN?

Comment: there is a relation, but it is cyclic and not linear. imagen 10 kids standing in a circle.
If I number the kids 1-10 the KNN would not be able to calculate the real distance between the kids.

Comment: https://mixedinkey.com/wp-content/themes/mixed-in-key/img/camalote-wheel-logo.png
I hope with pic would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could think about the distance between scales is to think of each scale as a 12-element binary vector where there's a 1 wherever a note is in the scale and a zero otherwise.

Then you can compute the Hamming distance between scales. The Hamming distance, for example, between a major scale and its relative minor scale should be zero because they both contain the same notes.

Here's a way you could set this up in Python

```
from enum import IntEnum
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import hamming

class Note(IntEnum):
    C = 0
    Db = 1
    D = 2
    Eb = 3
    E = 4
    F = 5
    Gb = 6
    G = 7
    Ab = 8
    A = 9
    Bb = 10
    B = 11

major = np.array((1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1))
minor = np.array((1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)) #WHWWHWW Natural Minor

# Transpose the basic scale form to a key using Numpy's `roll` function

cMaj = np.roll(major, Note.C) # Rolling by zero changes nothing
aMin = np.roll(minor, Note.A)
gMaj = np.roll(major, Note.G)
fMaj = np.roll(major, Note.F)

print('Distance from cMaj to aMin', hamming(cMaj, aMin))
print('Distance from cMaj to gMaj', hamming(cMaj, gMaj)) # One step clockwise on circle of fifths
print('Distance from cMaj to fMaj', hamming(cMaj, fMaj)) # One step counter-clockwise on circle of fifths
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can convert your features to something like `sin` as follows. Hear I have 10 values 1-10 and I am transforming them to keep their circular relation.

```
a = np.around(np.sin([np.deg2rad(x*18) for x in np.array(list(range(11)))]), 3)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a)
```

Output:

[image]

Through this feature engineering you can see that the circularity of your feature is encoded. The value of 0 is equal to 10.

Comment: this doesn't help with a nearest neighbor search at all, or at least, if it does this answer would really benefit from an explanation of how to implement

Comment: @Michael Delgado, look at the answer again. With this transformation, circularity of data has been provided to the model. For, implementation, it is quite straightforward. If the question provides us with samples I will provide that too.

Comment: is 2 really closer to 8 than 7?

Comment: Thank you Kermat, this is an interesting idea and I will explore it.
But as Michael mentioned 2 is closer to 8 than 7. I think your solution fits the scenario where the kids are in a squished circle, like a vertical ellipse.

Comment: Yes, actually I developed it based on the kids example!

Comment: I think this is a good start, but you need to implement in 2 dimensions so the locations are on a unit circle, not just transform with sin. then a 2D nearest neighbor algorithm would work.